# Solving progressive tax calculation for pre-tax income

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

#### Progressive Tax Rate Explanation

Progressive taxation works by taxing income within a certain bracket at different rates. For example:

| Bracket # | % tax rate within bracket | Min amount (exclusive) | Max amount (inclusive) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10% | 0 | 50,000 |
| 2 | 20% | 50,000 | 60,000 |
| 3 | 25% | 60,000 | n/a (>60,000) |

In the example above, the taxes on 100,000 in income would be 17,000 (5,000 from bracket #1, 2,000 from bracket #2, and 10,000 from bracket #3).

I'm currently computing this as the dot product of two vectors (with a "zero" bracket of 0%/0 max):
$$
([\textrm{bracket 1 rate}, \textrm{bracket 2 rate}, \textrm{bracket 3 rate}]-[\textrm{bracket 0 rate}, \textrm{bracket 1 rate}, \textrm{bracket 2 rate}]) \cdot [max(0, \textrm{income}-\textrm{bracket 0 max}), max(0, \textrm{income}-\textrm{bracket 1 max}), max(0, \textrm{income}-\textrm{bracket 2 max})]
$$

So, in the example above we do:
$$
\begin{align}
([0.1, 0.2, 0.25]-[0, 0.1, 0.2]) \cdot [max(0, 100000-0), max(0, 100000-50000), max(0, 100000-60000)] \\
([0.1, 0.1, 0.05]) \cdot [100000, 50000, 40000] \\
100000*0.1+50000*0.1+40000*0.05 \\
17000
\end{align}
$$

### Question

Using the progressive taxation formula above, we can get "take home pay" (income less taxes) by subtracting taxes from the income:
$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{take home pay} & = \textrm{income} - \left([\textrm{bracket 1 rate}, \textrm{bracket 2 rate}, \textrm{bracket 3 rate}]-[\textrm{bracket 0 rate}, \textrm{bracket 1 rate}, \textrm{bracket 2 rate}]) \cdot [max(0, \textrm{income}-\textrm{bracket 0 max}), max(0, \textrm{income}-\textrm{bracket 1 max}), max(0, \textrm{income}-\textrm{bracket 2 max})]\right)
\end{align}
$$

This means that in the example above, the post-tax "take home pay" is 83,000 (100,000 - 17,000).

I'm trying to solve this equation for income, so that I can plug in a given take home pay, and get the amount of pre-tax income I need to get that take home pay.

Any clue how to solve for income, or even approximate income necessary for a given take home pay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I$ be the total income and $P$ be take-home pay.  Then the taxes paid is $T = I - P$, where
$$T = \begin{cases}
0.1 I, & I \in [0, 50000] \\
5000 + 0.2(I - 50000), & I \in (50000, 60000] \\
7000 + 0.25(I - 60000), & I \in (60000, \infty).
\end{cases}$$
Hence
$$P = \begin{cases}
0.9 I, & I \in [0, 50000] \\
0.8 I + 5000, & I \in (50000, 60000] \\
0.75 I + 8000, & I \in (60000, \infty).
\end{cases}$$
Now all that remains is to invert this piecewise function.  We do this by solving each piece for $I$ and expressing the interval for each piece in terms of $P$.  So for instance,
$$P = 0.9I, \quad I \in [0, 50000]$$
implies that $$I = \frac{10}{9}P, \quad P \in [0, 45000].$$
The other cases are handled similarly; we obtain
$$I = \begin{cases}
\frac{10}{9}P, & P \in [0, 45000] \\
\frac{5}{4}(P - 5000), & P \in (45000, 53000] \\
\frac{4}{3}(P - 8000), & P \in (53000, \infty).
\end{cases}$$
This furnishes the total income $I$ needed to earn a take-home pay of $P$.

Comment: I guess you need to amend some careless mistake, as the tax rate in $(60000,+\infty)$ should be 0.25?

Comment: @AngaeMT Thank you--I have made the correction.

Comment: Thanks you! Based on your answer above, here is the solution using vectors, like my original formula:
$$ 
\textrm{income} = \textrm{take home pay} + ([1 / (1 - \textrm{bracket 1 rate}), 1 / (1 - \textrm{bracket 2 rate}), 1 / (1 - \textrm{bracket 3 rate})] - [1 / (1 - \textrm{bracket 0 rate}), 1 / (1 - \textrm{bracket 1 rate}), 1 / (1 - \textrm{bracket 2 rate})]) \cdot [max(0, \textrm{post tax}), max(0, \textrm{post tax} - ((1 - \textrm{bracket 1 rate}) * \textrm{bracket 1 max}), max(0, \textrm{post tax} - ((1 - \textrm{bracket 2 rate}) * \textrm{bracket 2 max})]
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can easily see that the function you want should be case-defined. Let's split into three cases. We let $P$ to be the take-home-payment and $I$ be the income.

If $I\le\$50000$, then certainly it only needs to pay tax $1$, so you have $P=0.9I$.

If $I\in (50000,60000]$, then $P=(I-50000)\times0.8+50000\times0.9=0.8I+5000$.

For $I>60000$, $P=(I-60000)\times0.75+(50000\times0.9+10000\times0.8)=0.75I+8000$.

In sum, the function you wants should be $$P(I)=\begin{cases}
0.9I&\text{for } I\le 50000\\0.8I+5000&\text{for }  50000<I\le60000\\0.75I+8000&\text{for } I>60000\end{cases}$$

**Edit.** Sorry for misunderstanding the question. But the idea is roughly the same. Since the above is an injective function, you can just take the inverse back.

For example, in $0<I\le 50000,$ $P=0.9I$, so $I=\dfrac{10}{9}P$ for $0<P\le0.9\times50000=45000$.

With similar manner, we can show that
$$I(P)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{10P}{9}&\text{for } P\le 45000\\\dfrac{5P}{4}-6250&\text{for }  45000<P\le53000\\\dfrac{4P}{3}-\dfrac{32000}{3}&\text{for } P>53000\end{cases}$$

Comment: OP was asking to start with $P$ and get $I$

Answer (score 0):

Start by assuming that the pre-tax income is in the lowest bracket, in which case you need take-home/0.9  Check whether the pre-tax is under 50000.  If yes, you are done.  If no, the first 50000 of pre-tax generates 45000 of take-home.  Subtract 45000 from the required take-home and assume you are in the second bracket, so the required pre-tax is (take-home - 45000)/0.8 + 50000  Check whether the pre-tax is under 60000.  If so you are done.  Otherwise go into the third bracket the same way.